# Verify Apache availability behind Azure Balancer for each VM

Tags: php, apache, azure, load-balancing, ping

**Status:**

- 2xA2 Azure VM with WAMP, behind Load Balancer
- endpoint monitoring set

**Question:**

1. How do i check the Apache availability for each VM (as port 80 is now balanced and i cannot individually check a machine)? 
   I need to check the response via a php script to be able to automatically deploy further custom actions.
2. Is there a way to manually check (via php, or online service) a probe.html(or specific file for each machine) that reside on each machine, in any way?

Answer (score 0):

If the two VMs exist on a private Azure VNET you could add a third machine to that VNET from which to perform the monitoring and then use the private IP address of each machine as your test endpoint.